# Compilation Error: "pointer can only be subtracted from another pointer"

Tags: c++, posix, math.h, cmath

Just learning *C++*, and I'm enjoying making my first program it's not much, it just solves math problems I'm having some issues with the distance formula as far as I know my logic is right `sqrt((x2-x1)+(y2-y1))`. However I am getting the error

> error C2113: '-' : pointer can only be subtracted from another pointer which is throwing me off.

BONUS question... if anybody could point me to a method of directing users back to the first menu when they have finished with a previous selection that would be cool. I'm assuming some sort of loops but I haven't covered that yet in my *C++* class.

Here is the code(sorry if it is messy but I haven't learned proper formatting yet)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


int selection;
int choice;
int choice2;
double height;
double length;
double a;
double x;
double y;
double const pi = 3.14;
double r;
double m;
double x1;
double x2;
double y1;
double y2;
double distance;

int main(){
cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"     MATH DESTROYER      "<<endl;
cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"  1-Geometry Solver      "<<endl;
cout<<"  2-Algebra Solver       "<<endl;
cout<<"  3-"<<endl;
cout<<endl;
cout<<"  Select Option number:  "<<endl;
cin>>selection;
cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;
    switch(selection){
    case 1:
    cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"     GEOMETRY SOLVER     ";cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<" 1-Perimeter of a square "<<endl;
    cout<<" 2-Area of a square      "<<endl;
    cout<<" 3-Perimeter of a rectangle"<<endl;
    cout<<" 4-Area of a rectangle   "<<endl;
    cout<<" 5-Perimeter of a circle "<<endl;
    cout<<" 6-Area of a circle      "<<endl;
    cout<<" Select Option number:   "<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
    cin>>choice;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    switch(choice){
            case 1:
                cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
                cout<<"  PERIMITER OF A SQUARE  "<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Enter Height"<<endl;
                cin>>height;
                cout<<"Enter Length"<<endl;
                cin>>length;
                cout<<"Perimiter of Square ="<<(height*2)+(length*2)<<endl;
                cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<endl;

                system("pause");
                return 0;

            case 2:
                cout<<"AREA OF A SQUARE"<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Enter Length"<<endl;
                cin>>length;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"FORMULA L^2";
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"AREA of Square ="<<pow(length,2)<<endl;//(pow)(length,2)= length to the power of 2 or lenght^2
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<endl;

                system("pause");
                return 0;

            case 3:
                cout<<"PERIMITER OF A RECTANGLE"<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Enter Height"<<endl;
                cin>>height;
                cout<<"Enter Length"<<endl;
                cin>>length;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<"FORMULA L2+H2";
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Perimiter of Rectangle ="<<(height*2)+(length*2)<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<endl;

                system("pause");
                return 0;

            case 4:
                cout<<"AREA OF A RECTANGLE"<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Enter Height"<<endl;
                cin>>height;
                cout<<"Enter Length"<<endl;
                cin>>length;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<"FORMULA L2+H2";
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Perimiter of Rectangle ="   <<height*length<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<endl;

                system("pause");
                return 0;

                case 5:
                cout<<"PERIMITER OF A CIRCLE"<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Enter Radius"<<endl;
                cin>>r;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"FORMULA peremiter=PI X D";
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Perimiter of circle ="<<pi*(r*2)<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<endl;

                system("pause");
                return 0;

                case 6:
                cout<<"AREA OF A CIRCLE"<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Enter Radius"<<endl;
                cin>>r;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"FORMULA PI X R^2";
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Area of Circle ="<<pi*(pow(r,2))<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<endl;

                system("pause");
                return 0;

    }
    case 2:
    cout<<"      ALGEBRA MASTER     "
    cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"    1-Distance Formula   "<<endl;
    cout<<"    2-Slope              "<<endl;
    cout<<"    3-Pythagorean Theorm "<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Select Option number:"<<endl;
    cin>>choice2;
        switch(choice2){
            case 1:
                cout<<"Distance Formula"<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Enter first y point (y1)"<<endl;
                cin>>y1;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Enter second y point (y2)"<<endl;
                cin>>y2;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Enter first x point (x1)"<<endl;
                cin>>x1;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Enter second x point (x2)"<<endl;
                cin>>x2;
                cout<<"D=sqrt (x2-x1)+(y2-y1)";
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Distance ="<<sqrt((x2-x1)+(y2-y1))<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<endl;

                system("pause");
                return 0;

                case 2:
                cout<<"AREA OF A CIRCLE"<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Enter Radius"<<endl;
                cin>>r;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"FORMULA PI X R^2";
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Area of Circle ="<<pi*(pow(r,2))<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<endl;

                system("pause");
                return 0;

                case 3:
                cout<<"AREA OF A CIRCLE"<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Enter Radius"<<endl;
                cin>>r;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"FORMULA PI X R^2";
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Area of Circle ="<<pi*(pow(r,2))<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<endl;

                system("pause");
                return 0;

    }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem is that your global variable `y1` may be conflicting with a function defined in `math.h` (or `cmath`). You can get around that by declaring your variables locally in the `main()` function, rather than as globals. That allows the variable name to mask the existing function, and avoids the conflict.

*EDIT: The alternative solution would be to rename `y1` to something else, e.g. `Y1` (upper-case).*

There are also a couple of other issues in the code. In two places you've got `cout<` instead of `cout <<`, and you're also missing a semi-colon.

Comment: What C function is named `y1`?

Comment: It was news to me too! Apparently it's something related to Bessel functions and differential equations: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zvm/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zvm.v610.edclv/y0.htm

Comment: Worked great thanks for pointing out my mistakes but this brings up a new issue can double handle negative numbers because I am getting wierd results in my distance formula

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield: That's a "IBM XL C/C++ for z/VM" extension, apparently; there is no mention of anything called `y1` in ISO/IEC 9899:1999. Fair enough though if this guy is using said extension.

Comment: Yes, `double` can handle negatives. I think the mistake in your equation is that you're not squaring the X and Y terms. It should be something like: `sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1))`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know. I think it's non-standard or deprecated, but it's definitely in some mainstream versions of `math.h` (although it's maybe conditionally-compiled out most of the time).

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield good catch on the bad formula duhh cant sqrt negative numbers without finding a solutoin for complex numbers    sqrt 144=12
sqrt -144=12i
 My college algebra teacher is shaking her head somewhere right now

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It is specified by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/y0.html) which is why you can't find it in the standard.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Oh, so it is. Y'know, that IBM document need only have said so!

Answer (score 3):

**Update**:

It looks like `y0`, `y1` and `yn` are [specified as part of POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/y0.html) which would explain why you won't find this documented in the *C* or *C++* standards:

> The y0(), y1(), and yn() functions shall compute Bessel functions of x of the second kind of orders 0, 1, and n, respectively.

The solution to *global namespace pollution* is to [declare your variables in your own namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12443604/1708801).

**Original**:

You have `<` in place of `<<` in a few of your `cout` calls, for example here:

```
cout<"FORMULA L2+H2";
    ^
```

should be:

```
cout<<"FORMULA L2+H2";
    ^^
```

Also in `clang` and `gcc`, I am getting a conflict with your global `y1` and a global `y1` from the `cmath` header, which makes this:

```
cout<<"Distance ="<<sqrt((x2-x1)+(y2-y1))<<endl;
                                     ^^
```

and a few other lines break, my solution was to rename `y1` but the better solution is to not use globals.